# Postgresql not getting updated programmatically

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I have a DAO layer which sets a flag as `yes` in database. 
Dao layer :

```
public boolean setActivationFlag(String msis, String activation) {
    String SQL = "update walletapp.users_kyc set ACTIVATED = :activation where MSIS = :msis";
    logger.info("update query:::::::::::::::"+ SQL);
    Map<String,String > namedParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    namedParameters.put("msis", msis);
    namedParameters.put("activation", activation);


    int noOfRows = nJdbcTemplate.update(SQL,namedParameters);
    logger.info("noOfRows"+ noOfRows);
    logger.info("User Activated Successfully : [ "+ msis + activation+" ]");
    return noOfRows > 0 ? true : false;
```

I am using spring for autowiring - `e.abcDao(msis, activation);`

But value is not being set in database. I have used character varying as the datatype in postgresql.

I found out that when I am sending `ID:460000/MSIS` as `msis` in the where  condition the query fails.  But it works for normal string like an `8788ccid`. Can anyone explain why it happens and if the `:` in the String can be handled?

I used split(":") to get only 460000/MSIS.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No errors. Just the row is not updated I database. Other update queries work fine for me except this.

Comment: What does `noOfRows` contain after the update? And what does "the query fails" mean?

Comment: `noOfRows`  contains 0

Comment: Then your table does not contain any rows that match the `where` criteria - simple as that

Comment: As I have edited, the value I passed in msis had `:` in it, because of which no row was updated. Anyways thanks for the excellent insight.